# change the redirection path after login

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I want to change the redirection success page for all user in drupal 7.
my login page in `mysite.com/user` after successfull login its getting redirected to the page `mysite.com/user/1`.butr I want to change the login successful redirection page to

```
mysite.com/node/1
```

I have tried as

```
function bartik_user_login(&$edit, $account)
{
  // Your logic will set $redirection to the desired location
  $redirection = 'node/1';

  // Unless there is already a redirection going, or the user is trying to reset his password, we redirect to $redirection.
  if (empty($_GET['destination'])
    && !is_null($redirection)
    && (!isset($_POST['form_id']) || $_POST['form_id'] != 'user_pass_reset'))
  {
    $_GET['destination'] = $redirection; // Should we use $edit['redirect'] instead..?
  }
}
```

Comment: You can read this usefull page https://www.drupal.org/node/683696

Answer (score 1):

Because the `$_GET['destination']` always exists (it is `user/{id}` in your case), so your assignment `$_GET['destination'] = $redirection` will never be reached.

Just remove `empty($_GET['destination']` from `if` condition and your code will work:

```php
function bartik_user_login(&$edit, $account)
{
  $redirection = 'node/1';

  if (!is_null($redirection)
    && (!isset($_POST['form_id']) || $_POST['form_id'] != 'user_pass_reset'))
  {
    $_GET['destination'] = $redirection;
  }
}
```